# java.lang.LinkageError: JAXB 2.1 API is being loaded from the bootstrap classloader with JAX-WS web service

Tags: web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, tomcat6, linkageerror

I know this is the very basic example of jax-ws web services but I am not able to resolve this error. I am following this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/
 and made the war file using build.xml using ant. But when i copy paste this war file to apache tomcat's webapps directory, it gets deployed but this url localhost:8084/HelloWorld/hello gives Error 404 (I have apache tomcat running at port no 8084). I have included the contents of the war file below:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, 
Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
                com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

sun-jaxws.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
  version="2.0">
  <endpoint
      name="HelloWorld"
      implementation="com.mkyong.ws.HelloWorldImpl"
      url-pattern="/hello"/>
</endpoints>
```

build.xml

```
<project name="HelloWorld" default="dist" basedir=".">
    <description>
        Web Services build file
    </description>
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src" location="src"/>
  <property name="build" location="build"/>
  <property name="dist"  location="dist"/>
  <property name="webcontent"  location="WebContent"/>

  <target name="init">
        <!-- Create the time stamp -->
        <tstamp/>
        <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
        <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init"
    description="compile the source " >
        <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="war" depends="compile"
    description="generate the distribution war" >

    <!-- Create the war distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/war"/>

    <!-- Follow standard WAR structure -->
    <copydir dest="${dist}/war/build/WEB-INF/" src="${webcontent}/WEB-INF/" />
    <copydir dest="${dist}/war/build/WEB-INF/classes/" src="${build}" />

    <jar jarfile="${dist}/war/HelloWorld-${DSTAMP}.war" basedir="${dist}/war/build/"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

HelloWorld.java

```
package com.mkyong.ws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

//Service Endpoint Interface
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface HelloWorld{

    @WebMethod String getHelloWorldAsString();

}
```

HelloWorldImpl.java

```
package com.mkyong.ws;

import javax.jws.WebService;

//Service Implementation Bean

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.mkyong.ws.HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld{

    @Override
    public String getHelloWorldAsString() {
        return "Hello World JAX-WS";
    }
}
```

Please point out where I am going wrong

Edit: I got the following exception in Tomcat Log:

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/HelloWorld]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1105)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1664)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1629)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1655)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1565)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1273)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
Nov 4, 2012 5:25:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory F:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\HelloWorld
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/HelloWorld]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1105)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1664)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: please somebody help
I want to develop web services

Comment: Your code looks ok, so I suspect your ant build config is broken. Do you not see any errors/exception in your logs during tomcat startup?

Comment: thank you for replying. i added the exception in tomcat log

Comment: Related problem (with explanation): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162159/supplying-a-different-version-of-jaxb-for-jax-ws-in-java-1-6

Answer (score 3):

You're experiencing this error as a result of a discrepancy between the version of the libraries that your program needs Vs the version that is shipped by default with your JDK. You're running a JAX-WS 2.2 (requiring a JAXB version of 2.2 minimum) webservice example but your JDK 6 and your tomcat installation ship with JAXB version 2.1, resulting in the exception you have.

To resolve this, use the JDK's [endorsed standards override mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/standards/) that essentially allows you to override default libraries/jars that are packaged as part of a vanilla installation of the JDK with newer versions of same.

1. Download the latest copies of the [JAXB api](http://jaxb.java.net/2.2.6/jaxb-ri-2.2.6.zip) and [JAX-WS](http://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.7/JAXWS2.2.7-20120813.zip) libraries and place in the `<JDK_HOME>\lib\endorsed` path, where `<JDK_HOME>` refers to the installation folder of your JDK (I'm presuming windows here). If the `endorsed` folder doesn't exist in that path, create it and place the fresh copy there.
2. Take the same downloads an place in your `<TOMCAT_HOME>\endorsed\` path for your tomcat installation. As before, if `endorsed` doesn't exist, create it.

You're good to go

Comment: Thanks a lot kolossus for replying. I followed your steps and the linkage error is gone!! but now there is some other exception(Edited the exception in original question). Please help me with that one too

Comment: @user1717415, tomcat startup could be failing for two related reasons 1. The jar `servlet.jar` may exist in more than one location within the tomcat folder. Verify this is not the case and make sure that jar only exists in the `TOMCAT_HOME/lib` folder

Comment: i have servlet-api.jar file contained in TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder only

Comment: @user1717415, ensure that you placed only the `jax-ws.api.jar` and `jaxb-api.jar` in the endorsed folder in tomcat. See [this](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2009/04/tip_for_using_j.html) blog post for a better detailed step-by-step

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JDK version 6 or lower. upgrade it.
I had faced same issue, after upgrading JDK serion to 7 it gone.